# Error caused while using round() function of Python. What can be the issue?

Tags: python

While using `round(2.9239,2)`, it produced an output 2.99999999 rather than 2.92. In stackoverflow, I had read that the best way to deal with this is use string formatting upon the output. If that's the only way, why do we even have a round function? It is not even consistent across all the numbers. As in, some numbers it gives the correct output, for some it doesn't.

Comment: Hm. Can't reproduce: `>>> round(2.9239,2)` yields `2.92`. I guess your 2.93 is a typo? This is Python 3.1.2

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and have no intentions to move to 3.1.2

Comment: Works for me (with 2.7.2). You'd need the worst FPU ever to get 2.92 represented internally as 2.999999999.

Comment: Remember that floating point numbers cannot precisely represent all real numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems (I'm also assuming a typo in the question)

Comment: `Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, May 24 2011, 15:30:26) [GCC] on linux3
>>> round(2.9239,2)
2.92`

Comment: I fixed the typo. Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: There's still a typo in your question: 2.999999999

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(I think you mean it should be `2.92` and the output that you get is `2.9199999999999999`.)

This is a classic problem with floating point arithmetic - the number 2.92 is not exactly expressible as a floating pointer number - in binary it would be an infinite sequence of digits, as ⅓ is in decimal.  This is nicely explained on the page on [floating point arithmetic](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in the Python documentation.  The [documentation for `round()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) explicitly mentions this problem.